# Scikit learn with digits

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**i don't understand**

iam trying to use scikit learn with matplotlib with digits dataset

this is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(digits.data, digits.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=2017)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print("Prediction: {}".format(pred))    
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

matplotlib plot image number 4, when i try to print the prediction it print to me this output everytime

```
Prediction: [8 1 3 8 5 8 1 4 9 7 5 2 1 4 3 2 4 9 5 4 1 9 2 4 7 8 9 3 1 7 5 7 6 2 0 5 7
 1 6 1 9 4 4 5 3 7 3 6 3 3 9 8 5 2 6 1 1 1 4 5 4 2 8 2 7 2 9 7 8 9 1 2 8 0
 7 8 9 0 1 5 4 0 0 9 2 6 7 8 6 5 1 3 1 8 7 7 2 2 2 6 7 4 1 7 2 5 8 3 4 2 3
 7 6 1 1 0 3 0 2 5 9 3 1 6 9 5 6 2 0 3 2 7 4 6 5 3 9 5 1 5 6 0 1 8 6 5 1 6
 2 1 2 5 0 2 3 4 2 4 9 4 4 2 3 9 2 9 8 2 5 9 9 7 3 7 8 1 4 9 2 9 5 1 8 7 4
 8 2 7 6 9 8 8 3 7 1 9 1 4 5 7 0 5 9 3 5 0 5 0 5 5 2 1 3 5 3 2 8 4 7 4 7 3
 7 2 9 5 6 2 8 0 5 0 2 1 9 2 9 6 1 0 1 7 6 3 1 0 3 2 4 0 6 1 2 1 6 2 8 2 7
 1 5 6 6 9 2 1 4 4 8 0 7 6 2 5 0 4 5 5 5 5 7 4 8 1 0 8 4 8 7 2 5 5 7 3 2 4
 4 7 8 2 0 7 1 4 0 9 6 1 8 5 5 1 5 6 1 7 1 5 5 8 4 6 6 0 6 5 0 9 8 0 8 0 9
 2 0 9 5 7 0 8 1 7 0 6 7 7 0 0 7 7 5 0 3 2 2 8 8 7 7 0]
```

i am trying to print the number in matplotlib but it shows me this output

i expect to print `prediction: 8`

Comment: What do you not understand? Please explain clearly. The `pred` array returns the prediction for all the samples present in `X_test`

Comment: you don't understand why your code print the same prediction everytime, do you?

Comment: thats  it, it print the same prediction every time

Comment: i trying to print the number in the matplotlib image, but it print this output

Comment: because you  passed X_test parameter to predict().

Comment: explain more. what parameter to pass in predict()

Comment: you only wanna predict the last digit, dont you?

Comment: you want this? `pred = clf.predict(digits.data[[-1], ])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is what people in the comments are trying to tell you:

`X_test` is not a single datapoint, but the *whole* of your test set. How many samples does it include?

```
X_test.shape
# (360, 64)
```

So, it includes 360 samples; hence, your `pred` variable must also contain predictions for all these 360 samples. Indeed:

```
pred.shape
# (360,)
```

You want to check the prediction for your first sample in `X_test`?

```
pred[0]
# 8
```

And what is the ground truth for this prediction?

```
y_test[0]
# 8
```

It seems you got a correct prediction for your first test sample indeed. You want to plot this sample (`X_test[0]`)? You should first reshape it back into `(8,8)`, since the <s>`train_test_split`</s> `load_digits()` function flattens the original 8x8 images to 1D arrays of length 64:

```
plt.imshow(X_test[0].reshape(8,8), cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Well, it looks like an 8 (kind of)...

Comment: Just a little correction. `train_test_split` dont flatten the shape of digits. The array returned by `load_digits().data` is already an array of `(n_samples, 64)`